# calculate the hours in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate in javascript the hours between jam_keluar and jam_masuk so that lama_parkir will be like:

lama_parkir = jam_keluar - jam_masuk // 4 hours

```js
function hitunglamaparkir(){
    var k = document.getElementById('jam_keluar').value;
    var m = document.getElementById('jam_masuk').value;
    var tentukan = (k - m);
    document.forms.formID.lama_parkir.value = tentukan;
}
```

```html
<form id="formID"  name="form2" method="post" action="proses.php">
  <tr>
    <td id="noborder">Jam Masuk</td>
    <td id="noborder">:</td>
    <td id="noborder"><input name="jam_masuk" type="text" id="jam_masuk" size="5" maxlength="15" value="10:30:00"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="noborder">Jam Keluar</td>
    <td id="noborder">:</td>
    <td id="noborder"><input name="jam_keluar" type="text" id="jam_keluar" size="5" onkeyup="hitunglamaparkir(this.value,getElementById('jam_keluar').value);" value="14:30:00"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="noborder">Lama Parkir</td>
    <td id="noborder">:</td>
    <td id="noborder"><input name="lama_parkir" type="text" id="lama_parkir" size="5" maxlength="15" readonly="readonly"/></td>

</form>
```

Comment: What exactly did you type in the textboxes? As far as I can tell, the result is being calculated correctly.

Comment: `ReferenceError: subtotal is not defined` - where is the `subtotal()` function?

Comment: Have you tried `parseInt()`? What is `subtotal()`? `this.value` seems to be the same as `getElementById(...).value`

Comment: I ran the code snippet in your question and entered a number in each of the first two inputs, and the third input correctly showed the difference. So how do you reproduce the problem? Why, when calling the function, do you pass values to it when the function itself doesn't use them? (Also, why the "php" tag?)

Comment: I mean to find the time difference. example: jam_masuk = 10:00:00 jam_keluar = 13:00:00 then the difference between these two is hour to lama_parkir: 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

This snippet determines the difference between jam_keluar and jam_keluar as such:

**`jam_keluar` - `jam_masuk` = `lama_parkir`**.

So we can determine this:

1. Your function is working properly
2. There is no need to call subtotal
3. There is no need for `lama_parkir` to be editable (make it `readonly`)

```js
function hitunglamaparkir(){
    var k = document.getElementById('jam_keluar').value;
    var m = document.getElementById('jam_masuk').value;
    var tentukan = (k - m);
    document.forms.formID.lama_parkir.value = tentukan;
}
```

```html
<form id="formID"  name="form2" method="post" action="proses.php">
  <tr>
    <td id="noborder">Jam Masuk</td>
    <td id="noborder">:</td>
    <td id="noborder"><input name="jam_masuk" type="text" id="jam_masuk" size="5" maxlength="15" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="noborder">Jam Keluar</td>
    <td id="noborder">:</td>
    <td id="noborder"><input name="jam_keluar" type="text" id="jam_keluar" size="5" onkeyup="hitunglamaparkir(this.value,getElementById('jam_keluar').value);"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="noborder">Lama Parkir</td>
    <td id="noborder">:</td>
    <td id="noborder"><input name="lama_parkir" type="text" id="lama_parkir" size="5" maxlength="15" readonly="readonly"/></td>

</form>
```

Comment: I want to find the time difference.
example:
jam_masuk = 10:00:00
jam_keluar = 13:00:00
then the difference between these two is hour to lama_parkir: 3 hours

Comment: Okay, I've updated the post.  It is calculating the difference now.